# Create "private" components for internal use in stencil.js

Tags: stenciljs

I'm building a library of stencil.js components that will be published on npm.
Internally, my components use sub-components that I do not wish to expose to the outside world.

Is there a way to define a "private" components that can be used internally by other components in the same namespace, but are not exposed externally?

Comment: If your components use them internally, then how could you not expose them? They'll have to become part of the bundled code, because without them your "public" components would not work. Maybe you can define an API for your public component lib to consume your "private components" and then create a separate, private package for those (kind of like an optional dependency of your public component lib).

Comment: Have you solved this?

Answer (score 1):

You can simply create a functional component which allows you to only render it inside of you parent web component, without exposing it externally.

Functional components:

- aren't compiled into web components,
- don't create a DOM node, don't
- have a Shadow DOM or scoped styles,
- don't have lifecycle hooks, are
- stateless.

Please check this doc, it is quite straight forward to use it:
https://stenciljs.com/docs/functional-components